# How to make horizontal lines sit beside circle bullets using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to accomplish the below using CSS:

[image]

Ideally, the length of the lines should depend on the number of circles (i.e. it should be longer if it's less than five, shorter if more than, and so on).

I tried to do this using the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="ng-modal-number-container">
   <div class="questionNumbers" ng-repeat="item in numberOfQuestions">
        <div class="questionNumberIcon">{{item}}</div><div class="questionNumberLine"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ng-modal-number-container {
    height:78px;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    width:auto;
    display:flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.questionNumbers {
    display:inline;
}

.questionNumberIcon {
    display:inline-block;
    width:45px;
    height:45px;
    border-radius:23px;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#000;
    line-height:45px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#fff;
    border:2px solid black;
 }

.questionNumberLine {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

However, what I got was this:

[image]

I'm sure there's something wrong with my CSS, I just don't know what. Hopefully you guys can point it out for me.

Any advice would be very much appreciated, as always.

Thank you.

**UPDATE 1:** As z0mB13 advised, I changed my ng-modal-number-container's justify content to the following:

```
.ng-modal-number-container {
    height:78px;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    width:auto;
    display:flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

I also added `width:100px` to `.questionNumberLine`, so this is how it looks like now:

[image]

Just a few more tweaks and I can adjust the location of the lines, however, is it possible to make the width of the line dynamic? I want it to be longer if there are fewer circles, and vice versa.

Thanks!

**UPDATE 2 (Answer):** Finally solved this thanks to thepio's tips. I'm posting my solution here in case somebody else encounters the same problem in the future.

Thanks thepio!

HTML:

```
<div class="question-content-wrapper">
    <div class="ng-modal-number-container">
        <div class="questionNumbers" ng-repeat="item in numberOfQuestions">
            <div class="questionNumberIcon">{{item}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ng-modal-number-container {    
    margin-top: 22px;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    width:auto;
    display:flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
}

.questionNumbers {
    margin-top:-23px;
}

.questionNumberIcon {
    width:45px;
    height:45px;
    border-radius:50%;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#000;
    line-height:42px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.question-content-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    height:78px;    
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-top:16px;
}
```

What it looks like now:

[image]

Comment: for spacing between the circles give "justify-content: space-around" for ng-modal-number-container

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a little example of one possibility how you could achieve something like you want. Sorry for not implementing it into your given code but you should be easily able to do it yourself.

```css
body {
  margin: 50px 20px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.container div {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: -40px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

A fiddle with your html structure: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/0opv207p/

Comment: Just to confirm, I'm going to define the line in the `.container`, right?

Comment: Well it depends on the situation. But basically you declare it on the wrapping element which is 100% (width) of the "timeline" you want. So the first and last circle starts from its edges.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I'll give this a try and give an update on how it turns out. :)

Comment: It works like a charm! Just needed to make adjustments to the content wrapper's padding to fit what our UX designer did. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, no problem! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 5):

This will account for multiple amount of bullets, and any width.

```css
.questionNumbers {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.questionNumberIcon {
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.questionNumberLine {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<main class="questionNumbers">
  <div class="questionNumberIcon">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="questionNumberLine"></div>
  <div class="questionNumberIcon">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="questionNumberLine"></div>
  <div class="questionNumberIcon">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="questionNumberLine"></div>
  <div class="questionNumberIcon">
    4
  </div>
</main>
```

If you're ending up with a line as your last element, just do:

```
.questionNumberLine:last-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

// These Set Of Circles And Lines Automatically Adjust At Any Resolution//

```css
.main-container{
 width:100%;
 height:200px;
 border:1px solid;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-left:10px;
}
.circle{
  
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:10%;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid #333;
  border-radius:50%;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:45px;
  float:left;
 
}
.line{
 width:15%;
 border:1px solid red;
 float:left;
  margin-top:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="circle">1</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="circle">2</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="circle">3</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="circle">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Except they are not circles